# Select a set of edges which create the largest graph given that some edges are mutually exclusive of others

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I'm trying to determine how to best tackle this problem.

Given a set of nodes and multiple, conflicting ways in which they could be connected I need to select the set of non-conflicting relations such that largest number of nodes remain in connected.

Example.

Here is a graph including all possible relations (edges) ignoring conflicts. Eg., this image doesn't depict the dependence of the edges on each other.
[image: Example Graph Structure]

All edges attached to a specific node are dependent on one another.  For simplicity each edge implies an attribute to each node it connects say A...Z.  If an edge connecting nodes 3 and 16 specifies attributes 3-B and 16-F, then all edges connecting 16 to other nodes must have attribute 16-F.  Similarly all edges connecting 3 to other nodes must have attribute 3-B.

Here is the same graph when specifying attribute F to node 16.  This attribute removes most edges leaving one edge connecting 16-4 and one edge connecting 16-3.  This has left no edges between 16-42.

(16 is near the left in both images.)
[image: Graph structure specifying 16-F]

This image does not illustrate that the edge connecting 3-42 will specify an attribute for node 42, say 42-X.  This will further constrain connections to 42 and further break up the graph. I have not displayed this because this is what my question pertains to.

I am looking for advice.

1. Is this a known problem?  Can you point me to any references?
2. How
   would you approach this problem?  My best idea is to iterate,
   starting at each edge, over all possible attributes.  Evaluate each
   partitioning and find which preserves the largest network.  This
   sounds challenging though and I could use some help.
3. If this is the solution is there a way using igraph in R to specify an "edge attribute constraint" and pull out the resulting, fragmented graph.

---

I have `dput` the graph here:

```
df = structure(list(nodeA = c(3L, 4L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 29L,   30L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 43L, 44L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 29L, 30L, 52L,   29L, 30L, 35L, 25L, 35L, 25L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 3L, 4L, 43L,   44L, 29L, 30L, 25L, 29L, 30L, 42L, 3L, 4L, 17L, 43L, 44L, 29L,   30L, 29L, 30L, 17L, 17L, 29L, 30L, 6L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 52L,   35L, 35L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 35L, 35L, 25L,   25L, 24L, 24L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 35L, 35L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L,   52L, 42L, 3L, 42L, 42L, 3L, 4L, 42L, 25L, 42L, 25L, 3L, 4L, 42L,   3L, 4L, 17L, 35L, 3L, 4L, 35L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 35L, 35L,   35L, 52L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 35L, 29L, 30L, 3L, 4L, 43L, 44L,   29L, 30L, 25L, 29L, 30L, 52L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 25L, 29L, 30L,   3L, 4L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 52L, 43L, 44L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L,   3L, 4L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 52L, 52L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 35L,   52L, 52L, 3L, 4L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 52L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L,   43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 17L, 17L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 43L,   44L, 29L, 30L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 3L, 4L, 25L, 25L, 16L, 16L,   3L, 4L, 43L, 44L, 24L, 3L, 4L, 52L, 52L, 17L, 35L, 35L, 35L,   17L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 35L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 3L, 4L, 17L, 25L, 17L,   17L, 29L, 30L, 25L, 3L, 4L, 29L, 30L, 3L, 4L, 17L, 17L, 17L,   35L, 3L, 4L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 29L, 30L, 43L, 44L, 43L, 44L, 29L,   30L, 17L, 6L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 43L, 44L,   29L, 30L, 3L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 3L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 17L,   17L, 42L, 42L, 25L, 42L, 25L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 42L, 17L, 17L,   42L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 25L, 29L, 30L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L,   43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 25L, 29L, 30L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 43L, 44L,   29L, 30L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L), nodeB = c(16L,   16L, 17L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 35L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 24L, 24L,   24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L,   24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 16L, 16L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 35L, 35L,   16L, 16L, 16L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 35L, 43L, 44L, 52L,   52L, 17L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 43L, 44L,   24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 43L, 44L, 24L, 24L, 25L,   25L, 43L, 44L, 29L, 30L, 43L, 44L, 17L, 24L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 16L,   16L, 17L, 35L, 17L, 35L, 16L, 16L, 52L, 16L, 16L, 6L, 25L, 16L,   16L, 52L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 43L, 44L, 25L, 25L, 29L, 30L, 43L,   44L, 17L, 42L, 42L, 16L, 16L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 35L, 35L,   35L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 16L, 16L, 24L, 24L, 25L,   25L, 35L, 17L, 17L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 16L, 16L, 24L, 24L, 25L,   25L, 25L, 35L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 29L, 30L, 16L, 16L, 24L,   24L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 43L,   44L, 3L, 4L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L,   25L, 25L, 16L, 16L, 35L, 35L, 3L, 4L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L,   16L, 16L, 29L, 30L, 6L, 25L, 29L, 30L, 42L, 16L, 16L, 25L, 52L,   16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 24L, 35L, 43L, 44L, 52L, 52L, 35L,   16L, 16L, 52L, 52L, 16L, 16L, 24L, 43L, 44L, 25L, 16L, 16L, 24L,   43L, 44L, 52L, 52L, 17L, 17L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 52L, 42L, 24L,   24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 42L, 24L,   24L, 25L, 25L, 42L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 43L, 44L, 4L, 17L, 35L,   17L, 35L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 16L, 43L, 44L, 4L, 4L, 24L, 24L,   25L, 25L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L,   35L, 35L, 35L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 24L, 24L,   25L, 25L, 35L, 35L, 35L, 35L), attributeA = c(25L, 25L, 130L,   110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 113L, 113L, 43L, 43L, 71L, 5L, 5L, 127L,   127L, 5L, 5L, 127L, 127L, 72L, 130L, 130L, 137L, 140L, 137L,   140L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 56L, 56L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 130L,   140L, 140L, 29L, 68L, 68L, 56L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 146L,   146L, 43L, 43L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 47L, 11L,   11L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 84L, 14L, 14L, 84L, 84L,   84L, 84L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 18L, 18L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 110L,   37L, 122L, 114L, 114L, 108L, 108L, 58L, 27L, 136L, 109L, 26L,   26L, 115L, 111L, 111L, 78L, 109L, 112L, 112L, 78L, 114L, 114L,   114L, 114L, 37L, 37L, 47L, 73L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 128L,   111L, 111L, 125L, 125L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 45L, 58L, 58L, 143L,   55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 126L, 136L, 136L, 44L, 44L, 56L, 56L, 56L,   56L, 145L, 68L, 68L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 128L, 128L, 58L, 58L,   58L, 58L, 143L, 146L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 126L, 70L, 70L, 129L,   129L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 73L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 61L, 62L, 62L,   62L, 62L, 124L, 124L, 91L, 91L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 63L, 64L, 64L,   64L, 64L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 65L, 135L, 135L, 58L, 136L, 127L, 127L,   57L, 57L, 143L, 143L, 68L, 138L, 138L, 143L, 143L, 80L, 136L,   126L, 126L, 109L, 139L, 139L, 128L, 80L, 110L, 112L, 113L, 30L,   141L, 141L, 135L, 70L, 125L, 125L, 126L, 126L, 142L, 69L, 69L,   128L, 128L, 144L, 144L, 138L, 128L, 128L, 142L, 145L, 145L, 139L,   129L, 129L, 130L, 130L, 121L, 121L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 79L, 91L,   109L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 82L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 88L, 88L, 88L,   88L, 97L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 92L, 118L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 94L, 107L,   107L, 89L, 138L, 111L, 140L, 113L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 116L, 1L,   134L, 134L, 92L, 19L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 135L, 128L, 138L, 138L,   136L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 137L, 130L, 140L, 140L,   138L, 138L, 138L, 138L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 139L, 140L, 140L, 140L,   140L, 138L, 140L, 144L, 146L), attributeB = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L,   5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L,   7L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L,   11L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 17L, 17L,   17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L,   23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L,   29L, 29L, 29L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 37L, 37L, 37L, 37L,   37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L,   41L, 41L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 43L, 43L,   43L, 43L, 43L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 45L,   45L, 45L, 45L, 45L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 46L, 47L, 47L,   47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 48L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 49L,   49L, 49L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 51L, 52L,   52L, 52L, 52L, 54L, 54L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L,   57L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 58L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 60L, 60L, 60L,   60L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L, 66L,   67L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 72L,   72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 72L, 77L, 77L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 79L, 80L,   81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 85L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 87L, 89L,   91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 93L, 96L, 96L, 97L, 108L,   108L, 110L, 110L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 117L, 117L, 117L, 118L,   122L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 125L, 126L, 126L, 126L,   126L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 127L, 128L, 128L, 128L,   128L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 130L, 135L, 137L,   141L, 143L)), .Names = c("nodeA", "nodeB", "attributeA", "attributeB"  ), row.names = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 18L,   19L, 20L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 31L, 32L, 35L, 36L, 37L,   38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 59L, 60L, 62L, 63L, 64L,   65L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 78L, 82L, 83L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 96L,   97L, 98L, 99L, 108L, 109L, 112L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 120L,   121L, 122L, 129L, 131L, 134L, 135L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 146L,   147L, 153L, 154L, 156L, 157L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 168L, 169L,   175L, 176L, 178L, 179L, 183L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 196L, 197L,   198L, 201L, 204L, 206L, 208L, 209L, 213L, 216L, 217L, 221L, 222L,   225L, 226L, 230L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 248L, 249L, 255L, 256L,   259L, 260L, 264L, 265L, 272L, 276L, 277L, 284L, 285L, 287L, 288L,   289L, 290L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 308L,   309L, 310L, 315L, 316L, 318L, 319L, 320L, 321L, 325L, 333L, 334L,   336L, 337L, 338L, 339L, 347L, 348L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L,   359L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 368L, 369L, 373L, 374L, 381L, 382L, 384L,   385L, 386L, 387L, 390L, 395L, 396L, 397L, 398L, 406L, 407L, 408L,   409L, 411L, 412L, 416L, 417L, 421L, 422L, 423L, 424L, 430L, 431L,   432L, 433L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 441L, 447L, 448L, 450L, 452L, 454L,   455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 468L, 472L, 473L, 476L, 477L, 481L,   483L, 484L, 485L, 488L, 493L, 494L, 495L, 501L, 504L, 508L, 511L,   512L, 513L, 514L, 516L, 518L, 519L, 520L, 523L, 524L, 526L, 528L,   529L, 534L, 535L, 538L, 539L, 540L, 543L, 544L, 550L, 555L, 556L,   558L, 561L, 562L, 564L, 565L, 576L, 577L, 582L, 583L, 584L, 585L,   590L, 594L, 596L, 597L, 598L, 599L, 605L, 606L, 607L, 608L, 613L,   614L, 615L, 616L, 620L, 622L, 623L, 624L, 625L, 629L, 631L, 632L,   633L, 634L, 643L, 644L, 647L, 657L, 660L, 665L, 666L, 673L, 674L,   675L, 676L, 691L, 692L, 693L, 696L, 700L, 705L, 706L, 707L, 708L,   711L, 712L, 713L, 720L, 721L, 722L, 723L, 728L, 729L, 730L, 731L,   733L, 734L, 735L, 741L, 742L, 743L, 744L, 750L, 751L, 752L, 753L,   759L, 760L, 761L, 762L, 772L, 777L, 787L, 790L), class = "data.frame")

library(igraph)
g = graph.data.frame(df)
plot(g, vertex.size = 6, edge.arrow.mode=1, edge.arrow.size = 0)

> head(df)
  nodeA nodeB attributeA attributeB
1     3    16         25          1
4     4    16         25          1
5    42    17        130          1
7    43    24        110          1
8    44    24        110          1
9    29    25        110          1
```

In the above, row 1 `attributeA` is the exclusive attribute for node 3 such that all other edges connecting to node 3 must have attribute 25. Similarly, `attributeB` indicates that all edges connecting to node 16 must have the attribute 1. It is not necessary that row 1 be an edge, but it is necessary that no retained edges conflict.

[image: Subset for playing]

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working through this problem I stumbled upon a simpler solution. It seems my formulation of the problem was making the answer hard to see.

#### The core of the matter is: when two different constraints are applied to a node it effectively becomes two distinct nodes.

Framing the challenge in this way allows us to rapidly construct graphs for each set of constraints.  We can then quickly inspect these, look at the size, and (as my original question desired) select the set of constraints which preserves the largest graph.

```
g = graph.data.frame(df); plot(g, vertex.size = 6, edge.arrow.mode=1, edge.arrow.size = 0)
```

[image: Initial Graph]

```
# Combine the node and the rule into a new, unique node id referencing both the node and the constraint
df.split = c(df[,1:2]) + df[,3:4]*1E3 

# Keep track of edge numbers in this dataset for later
df.split = cbind(df.split, row = seq(nrow(df))) 

g.split = graph.data.frame(df.split); plot(g.split, vertex.size = 6, edge.arrow.mode=1, edge.arrow.size = 0)
```

[image: Graph with nodes as node+constraint]

```
# Decompose into unlinked sub graphs and count the edges in each
g.list = decompose.graph(g.split)
g.list.nodenum = sapply(g.list, ecount)  

head(g.list.nodenum[order(g.list.nodenum, decreasing=T)])
[1] 9 8 5 5 5 5

# Select the largest subgraph
g.sub = g.list[[order(g.list.nodenum, decreasing=T)[1]]]
plot(g.sub)
```

[image: Largest subgraph]

```
# Find what edges these were in the original dataset
originaledges = E(g.sub)$row
originaledges
[1] 129 157 130 158 131 159 212 213 132

# Play with the resulting graph, the largest graph which obeys constraints at all nodes.
df.largest = df[originaledges,]

df.largest
    nodeA nodeB attributeA attributeB
292    25    35         45         41
352    29    25         58         45
293    29    35         58         41
353    30    25         58         45
294    30    35         58         41
354    52    25        143         45
476    52    29        143         58
477    52    30        143         58
295    52    35        143         41

g.largest = graph.data.frame(df.largest); plot(g.largest, vertex.size = 6, edge.arrow.mode=1, edge.arrow.size = 0)
```

[image: Largest non-conflicting subgraph]

Hopefully this helps someone someday!

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a known problem? Can you point me to any references?

This is quite an interesting problem, and not one that I've encountered before.

> How would you approach this problem?

I would approach this problem from an integer programming perspective. The decision variables will be used to select the attribute of each node (only edges labeled with the attributes of both of their endpoints will be allowed). Further, we will select a "root node" that we expect to be in the large connected component, and we will create flow outward from this root node. Each other node will have demand 1, and flow will only be possible over valid edges. We will maximize the amount of flow pushed out from the root node; this will be the number of other nodes in the large component.

To achieve this formulation, I would create two classes of variables:

- **Node attribute variables**: For each node `i` and attribute `a`, I would create a binary variable `z_ia` that is 1 if node `i` is assigned attribute `a` and 0 otherwise.
- **Flow variables**: For each edge from node `i` to `j` (I assume "from" is `nodeA` in your data frame and "to" is `nodeB` in your data frame), variable `x_ij` indicates the amount of flow from `i` to `j` (negative values indicate flow from `j` to `i`).

We also have a number of different constraints:

- **Each node only has 1 attribute**: This can be achieved with `\sum_{a\in A} z_ia = 1` for each node `i`, where `A` is the set of all attributes.
- **Edge flows are 0 if the edge is not valid**: For each edge from `i` to `j` with attributes `a` and `b`, respectively, we will have `x_ij <= n*z_ia`, `x_ij <= n*z_jb`, `x_ij >= -n*z_ia`, and `x_ij >= -n*z_jb`. In all four constraints, `n` is the total number of nodes. These constraints will force `x_ij=0` if `z_ia=0` or `z_jb=0`, and otherwise will not be binding.
- **The net flow to any non-root node falls in [0, 1]**: This constraint ensures that all outflow must come from the root, so nodes can only get flow if they are connected to the root. For each non-root node `i` with edges incoming from node set `I` and edges outgoing to node set `O`, these constraints are of the form `\sum_{j\in I} x_ji - \sum_{j\in O} x_ij >= 0` and `\sum_{j\in I} x_ji - \sum_{j\in O} x_ij <= 1`.

The objective is to maximize the amount of flow out of the root node `r`. If `r` has incoming edges from nodes in set `I` and outgoing edges to nodes in set `O`, then this objective (which we maximize) is `\sum_{j\in O} x_ji - \sum_{j\in I} x_ij`.

With these variables and constraints in place, all you need to do is specify the root node `r` and solve; the solution will indicate the best possible assignment of attributes to nodes, assuming that `r` is in the largest component. If you re-solved for each root node `r`, you would end up with the global optimal assignment.

The following in an implementation of this approach with the `lpSolve` package in R:

```
library(lpSolve)

optim <- function(df, r) {
  # Some book keeping
  nodes = c(df$nodeA, df$nodeB)
  u.nodes <- unique(nodes)
  if (!r %in% u.nodes) {
    stop("Invalid root node provided")
  }
  n.node <- length(u.nodes)
  attrs = c(df$attributeA, df$attributeB)
  node.attrs <- do.call(rbind, lapply(u.nodes, function(x) {
    data.frame(node=x, attr=unique(attrs[nodes == x]))
  }))
  n.na <- nrow(node.attrs)
  n.e <- nrow(df)

  # Constraints limiting each node to have exactly one attribute
  node.one.attr <- t(sapply(u.nodes, function(i) {
    c(node.attrs$node == i, rep(0, 2*n.e))
  }))
  node.one.attr.dir <- rep("==", n.node)
  node.one.attr.rhs <- rep(1, n.node)

  # Constraints limiting edges to only be used if both attributes are selected
  edge.flow <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_len(n.e), function(idx) {
    i <- df$nodeA[idx]
    j <- df$nodeB[idx]
    a <- df$attributeA[idx]
    b <- df$attributeB[idx]
    na.i <- node.attrs$node == i & node.attrs$attr == a
    na.j <- node.attrs$node == j & node.attrs$attr == b
    rbind(c(-n.node*na.i, seq_len(n.e) == idx, -(seq_len(n.e) == idx)),
          c(-n.node*na.j, seq_len(n.e) == idx, -(seq_len(n.e) == idx)),
          c(n.node*na.i, seq_len(n.e) == idx, -(seq_len(n.e) == idx)),
          c(n.node*na.j, seq_len(n.e) == idx, -(seq_len(n.e) == idx)))
  }))
  edge.flow.dir <- rep(c("<=", "<=", ">=", ">="), n.e)
  edge.flow.rhs <- rep(0, 4*n.e)

  # Constraints limiting net flow on non-root nodes
  net.flow <- do.call(rbind, lapply(u.nodes, function(i) {
    if (i == r) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    rbind(c(rep(0, n.na), (df$nodeB == i) - (df$nodeA == i),
          -(df$nodeB == i) + (df$nodeA == i)),
          c(rep(0, n.na), (df$nodeB == i) - (df$nodeA == i),
          -(df$nodeB == i) + (df$nodeA == i)))
  }))
  net.flow.dir <- rep(c(">=", "<="), n.node-1)
  net.flow.rhs <- rep(c(0, 1), n.node-1)

  # Build the model
  mod <- lp(direction = "max",
            objective.in = c(rep(0, n.na), (df$nodeA == r) - (df$nodeB == r),
                             -(df$nodeA == r) + (df$nodeB == r)),
            const.mat = rbind(node.one.attr, edge.flow, net.flow),
            const.dir = c(node.one.attr.dir, edge.flow.dir, net.flow.dir),
            const.rhs = c(node.one.attr.rhs, edge.flow.rhs, net.flow.rhs),
            binary.vec = seq_len(n.na))
  opt <- node.attrs[mod$solution[1:n.na] > 0.999,]
  valid.edges <- df[opt$attr[match(df$nodeA, opt$node)] == df$attributeA &
                    opt$attr[match(df$nodeB, opt$node)] == df$attributeB,]
  list(attrs = opt,
       edges = valid.edges,
       objval = mod$objval)
}
```

It can solve the problem for subsets of the nodes in your original graph, but it becomes quite slow as you include an increasing number of nodes:

```
# Limit to 5 nodes
keep <- c(3, 4, 6, 16, 42)
df.play <- df[df$nodeA %in% keep & df$nodeB %in% keep,]
(opt.play <- optim(df.play, 42))
# $attrs
#    node attr
# 24    3   50
# 45    4   50
# 50   42   91
# 60   16  127
# 87    6  109
# 
# $edges
#     nodeA nodeB attributeA attributeB
# 416    42     3         91         50
# 417    42     4         91         50
# 
# $objval
# [1] 2
```

That run took 15 seconds. To speed this up, you could consider switching to a more powerful solver such as cplex or gurobi. These solvers are free for academic use but non-free otherwise.

> If this is the solution is there a way using igraph in R to specify an "edge attribute constraint" and pull out the resulting, fragmented graph.

Yes, given the attributes you can easily subset and plot the graph. For the 5-node example that I solved above:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(opt.play$edges, vertices=unique(c(df.play$nodeA, df.play$nodeB)))
plot(g, vertex.size = 6, edge.arrow.mode=1, edge.arrow.size = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the well thought out reply.  I really appreciate it, and I have learned a lot from your example.  It is going to take me some time to digest your answer but I wanted to thank you first! I'll also wait a bit for possible, other input before accepting your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it was really valuable to me.  One I learned of the concept of integer programming and got an idea of how one would achieve something like this in a more complex case.  In my case, however, I think I have arrived at a simpler solution.  See my answer below.  It seems your answer would be valuable when flow between nodes was continuous and not binary - something the simple approach below cannot achieve.  Please let me know if you see any objections to this answer - I'm sorry for having proposed an answer to my own question!